# Удалить дату из строчного значения

Tags: mysql, sql

есть колонка с примерным значением "text-text-20-11-2018". Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу удалить эту дату из конца строк в которых она есть (есть не во всех строках)? Записей очень много, поэтому не хотелось бы через php цикл проходить

Comment: Укажите точно версию MySQL. А в принципе - берём последние 10 символов, проверяем на шаблон даты, если соответствует - режем.

Comment: @Akina 5.5.52. А можно пример? Это можно сделать только sql запросом, без php?

Comment: Конечно, запросом. На зачем тут PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если совсем тупо (не проверяя валидность даты), то, например, так:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET field = LEFT(field, LENGTH(field)-10)
WHERE RIGHT(field,10) LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Работает, если заменить LIKE на RLIKE (LIKE с использованием регулярных выражений). Очень простое решение, спасибо